# take the structure of any project

Tags: structure

I have seen the project structure on readMe, how can I take this structure of my project, any program? any website. doesn't seems right to me to create by hand?
[image]

Comment: You can use [tree.nathanfriend.io](https://tree.nathanfriend.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a very simple way to get it.

Navigate to the root folder of your project and run `tree` from your terminal. You should get something like this:

```
project_root
│   README.md    
│
└───some_folder
│   │   another_file.txt
│   │   some_code.code
│   │
│   └───some_subfolder
│       │   some_more_code.txt
│       │   another_file.txt
│       │   a_picture.png
│       │   ...
│   
└───another_folder
    │   more_files.txt
    │   more_code.code
    ...
```

Now you can copy and paste this tree into your README file, wrapping it in triple backticks - ``` to get the markdown styling.

Answer (score 0):

https://ascii-tree-generator.com/  --> by hand ***
or ***
tree command in powershell  --> auto

Answer (score 0):

For your case I will do:

1. Go to the directory from where you want to have the root of the tree
2. Run the command `tree -d > my_tree_structure.txt`

**Note:** that you can limit the deph of tree using `tree -d -L <level>`. For only directories and its sub-directories from the root you will use `tree -d -L 2`.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue for so long i tried many types of module for tree but didn't work as i wanted but here i made a python module for current tree directory

run this :
`pip install dir-tree-drh` read the read documentation on https://github.com/dragon-devs/dir-tree-drh. i'm gonna update to more advance.

give it a star if it helps you.